# Using "/" in filename while creating a file directory URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I am making a URL, where it took the filename and create a folder with those names. But if the name contains "`/`", the URL is breaking and the undesired location is created.

Ex:

```
 var fileDirectory = $(".username").text()+"/"+$('#class').val()+"/"+$('#projectCode').val();
```

when projectCode return a name with "/" , for example : `magc/90` ; It create "`magc`" and "`90`" two different folder while i want it to be "`magc/90`" folder.

I used Replace function that works, But I want to store the Original project code here.

Anyway to do this . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Maybe you want to use the url encoded form magc%2F90 ?

Comment: I'm confused about why you're using slashes in a file name

Comment: @Maksim this work on saving files. Now i have to see how could i get those file in java .

Comment: @LayneBernardo Names are user specific . They named them by their file structure .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `/` in your filenames. Most OS either use `/` or `\` as delimiter. Some might also use `.`, `:` or `>`.

If you want to do something like this `mgic/90` use `-` or `_` as delimiter.

Comment: i have done this trick already . Still I was thinking if any way to  unchange  it and make this work done .

Comment: If i were you I'd not try to search a way of saving your filenames with `/` in it. One the one hand, it sounds confusing why someone would do that. And on the other hand, you can create a mess in your file system.